# docker_gwbridge collision is possible?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

If the subnet allocated for the docker_gwbridge falls on another subnet of the network will a collision take place?

Consider there is a host in the internal network with IP address 192.168.0.1/24, which is multiple hops away from a docker host. Assuming in this case that docker_gwbridge is created manually with the subnet 192.168.0.0/24 while the overlay network 10.0.0.0/24 is created afterwards. If I do :

$ docker exec cont1 ping 192.168.0.1

will the container know that it tries to access another host but not its bridging interface?

Thanks